# How is called this jquery effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like a javascript effect at this site http://sputniknews.com/ . 
Especially, when you move mouse on a (div) news , and news text fade-in over image background, and  image background fade out. 
How it is called technically ? (So i can search via google) 
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure that effect has a universally agreed upon name.

Comment: Well, quite sad if you have to use js for this, can be done with pure css, pseudo selector :hover is well supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I don't think you'll need any kind of JavaScript for this. All you need is some css, using the pseudo class :hover and a bit of hide and display. There are many examples out there in the wild, here is one: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/OriginalHoverEffects/

Basically you have an html container (An A-Tag for example), containing an image, a short and a long version of your news, on :hover you switch display of them, enhance this with some transitions for modern browsers and you'll even get something more fancy - without a single line of JavaScript code.

```
<a class="teaser" href="#">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320/sports/" />
    <span class="image-info">
        <!-- this is visible per default -->
        <span class="abstract">
            <strong>Title</strong>
            <em>Short description</em>
        </span>
        <!-- this is visible on hover -->
        <span class="description">
            <strong>Long Title</strong>
            <em>Long description.</em>
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

The container has a relative position, so the info can be placed absolute - at bottom per default, the info itself has a semi-transparent background (best is rgba - as a fallback for older browsers you could use a png image file).

```
.teaser {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.teaser .image-info {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    /* transparent background color, 
       easy fallback could be a transparent 
       png image as background */
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

img {
    /* to avoid spaces */
   float: left;
}

/* initial display inside the container */
.teaser span {
    display: block;
}

.teaser: .description {
    display: none;
}

/* on mouseover switch display */
.teaser:hover .abstract {
    display: none;
}

.teaser:hover .description {
    display: block;
}

/* cover the complete image */
.teaser:hover .image-info  {
    height: 100%;
}
```

I put together a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekmy38ga/) to demonstrate this principle. Not as fancy as the mentioned examples, just to explain the idea.